# Error while trying to run php system

Tags: php

I have uploaded cms system to my webhosting that is supposed to read/write data to a remote MSSQL server.

while trying to run the site, I'm getting a blank page.

Looking at the log file, this is the error i get there:

```
Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.0
Version: 1.0
Date: 2014-08-13 22:35:52
Fields: date time s-sitename s-computername s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs-version cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken
2014-08-13 22:35:52 W3SVC40 flox48 82.166.0.201 GET / - 80 - 104.131.210.221 HTTP/1.0 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+NetcraftSurveyAgent/1.0;++info@netcraft.com) - - www.harel-tax.co.il 500 0 0 236 364 437
```

Can anyone tell me what it means ?

thanks

Comment: "Internal Error 500: The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request." This can be any number off reasons- often the db connection is borked.

Answer (score 0):

500 is "Internal server error", check your error_log file for the actual error.  It means there's a problem with your script or configuration files.

Comment: Can't really figure what is causing the problem, willing to pay to solve this, if anyone wanna take a look - add me on skype - l2menuval

Comment: You are looking in the wrong log file.  Use Event Viewer (on the start menu) to find your error log, then paste the error here.

Comment: I'm using godaddy webhosting, where is it located ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know.  They should give you a control panel, and there should be an error log in there somewhere - you'll just have to look around or look in their help.